# Cómo insertar Registros en Tablas que están relacionadas entre sí

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**Estructura de las Tablas:**

```
create table Empleado(
       Nombre Varchar(15) not null,
       Apellido1 varchar(15),
       Apellido2 varchar(15),
       Dni int(10),       
       FechaNac date,
       Direccion varchar(30),
       Sexo varchar(1),
       Sueldo int(10),
       SuperDni int(10),
       Dno int(10) ,
       primary key(Dni)
);

create table Departamento(
       NombreDpto Varchar(15) not null,
       NumeroDpto int(10) not null,
       DniDirector int(10),
       FechaIngresoDirector date,
       primary key (NumeroDpto),
       foreign key(DniDirector)references Empleado(Dni) 
);

alter table Empleado add foreign key(Dno) references  Departamento(NumeroDpto);
```

**Ejecución de la Sentencia:**

```
insert into Empleado Values
('Jose','Perez','Perez',123456789,'1965-09-01','Eloy I,98','H',3000,333445555,5);
```

Al realizar una insercion me sale el siguiente error:

> 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`BDEmpresa`.`Empleado`, CONSTRAINT `Empleado_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`Dno`) REFERENCES `Departamento` (`NumeroDpto`))

Comment: El registro de la clave foranea que esta en empleado debe de exister en la tabla Departamento.

Comment: No obstante lo que dice J. Castro estamos en un problema de **diseño de la base de datos** ya que tienes también una `clave foránea` en **Departamento** donde utilizas como conexión el campo `DniDirector`. Esto significa "*no puedo ingresar un registro en Departamento si el DniDirector no hace referncia a un Dni de Empleado*", en el caso de añadir un registro a Departamento. Y si añades en Empleado "*no puedo ingresar un registro en Empleado si el Dno no hace referencia a un NumeroDpto de Departamento*". **¿Cómo entonces haces para ingresar el primer registro en cualquiera de las dos?**

Comment: Deberias de quitar esa llave foranea de empelado en departamentos y solo tener en empleado a que departamento pertenece seria una relación 1:m

Comment: Ese es el problema, tambien intente primero poblar la tabla Empleados y despues agregar Dno como clave foranea y no se puede

Comment: Hace unas horas realizo un examen cuya base de datos debía ser hecha con ese esquema,, pude realizar el esquema pero después nos pidieron poblarla y no lo conseguí por la cuestión de las claves .

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es del diseño de la base de datos ya que un departamento pueden contener uno o muchos empleados y un empleado solo puede estar en un departamento, la relación seria de 1:M como en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: Relación]

Entonces dada esta relación tu llave foránea estaria de parte del empleado, partiendo de eso tu base de datos quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
create table Departamento(
    NumeroDpto int(10) not null,
    NombreDpto Varchar(15) not null,
    primary key (NumeroDpto) 
 );    

create table Empleado(
    Nombre Varchar(15) not null,
    Apellido1 varchar(15),
    Apellido2 varchar(15),
    Dni int(10),       
    FechaNac date,
    Direccion varchar(30),
    Sexo varchar(1),
    Sueldo int(10),
    SuperDni int(10),
    Dno int(10) ,
    primary key(Dni)
);

alter table Empleado add foreign key(Dno) references  Departamento(NumeroDpto);
```

Toma en cuenta que siempre para la realización de tus tablas debes de crear primero las que no tengan relación con ninguna otra tabla para que no te vaya a marcar error. Tus inserts quedarian asi:

```
insert into Departamento Values
(5 ,'Recursos Humanos');

insert into Empleado Values
('Jose','Perez','Perez',123456789,'1965-09-01','Eloy I,98','H',3000,333445555,5);
```

Comment: si el problema es el diseño entonces el profesor esta demente y es imposible realizarlo como en el esquema que nos dio, gracias por tu opinión J. Castro

Comment: Como esta en el diagrama se tendria que almacenar en otra tabla la cual seria para el dniDirector y departamento

Comment: Bueno, gracias por su ayuda  :D

Answer (score 0):

si crees que un departamento puede contener muchos empleados y un empleado puede pertencer a varios departamentos la relacion seria de muchos a muchos entonces debes crear una tercera tabla llamada

**Depa_Empleados**
donde llamas a ambas claves
-primary key departamento
-primary key empleados